# Why Hoogle is not working under EclipseFP on my machine?

Tags: eclipse, haskell, hackage, hoogle

Environment:

- Windows 8 x64
- Behind HTTP proxy
- Eclipse Version: Kepler Service Release 1 Build id: 20130919-0819
- EclipseFP 2.5.4 correctly installed and working
- Haskell Platform 2013.2
- Environment variable *http_proxy* is set correctly
- Machine has working internet on its browsers
- "hoogle String" is working as expected from command prompt (executed from the path that is found in EclipseFP settings - *C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin\hoogle.exe*) and return lot of results
- Clean installation of *Haskell Platform*, then *Eclipse*, then *EclipseFP*. All options are by default. After I installed *EclipseFP* it asked me to install *build-wrapper* and other utils. I installed them, too for the current user.

But search in Hoogle window in Eclipse is doing nothing. No error message, no search results, no nothing. 
What could be the problem? Could someone help me find it?

[image: EclipseFP settings]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the EclipseFP "Helper executables" preferences window if it is pointing to your Hoogle installation. If not, you may click the middle button (of those three besides the text box where the Hoogle address should be) to automatically find the correct installation in your machine.

If it is not the problem, I would advise you to reformulate your question and put more information, such a screenshot of your preferences window.

Anyway, follows a example of my preference window

[image]

Comment: Path is correct and from that path in Command line everything works fine. All options there are the default one after clean install of Eclipse + EclipseFP.

Comment: May be EclipseFP bug?

Comment: What does happen if you try to update the Hoogle database with the command 'hoogle data' in the command line? Does it work?

Concerning your suggestion, it may be a bug. But, first, try to follow the steps suggested at the [EclipseFP website](http://eclipsefp.github.io/dev.html), particularly 10th step.

Finally, Moresmau is a very open minded programmer and would love to solve your problem. In this way, I'd recommend you to report it at the project issues page. But I'm sure you'll find your solution in [this discussion](https://github.com/JPMoresmau/eclipsefp/issues/140).

Comment: Wow! It worked after running 'hoogle data' from the location where it is set in EclipseFP! Thanks a lot!

Comment: It worked only the first time... After next starting of Eclipse it stopped again.

Comment: "Only start Browser when a Haskell perspective is open" MUST be turned off. Then everything is working right. I think that this is a bug and it is not recognizing that Haskell perspective is open.